# How to build a time series with Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

i have a database that contains all flights data for 2019. I want to plot a time series where the y-axis is the number of flights that are delayed ('DEP_DELAY_NEW')and x-axis is the day of the week. 
The day of the week column is an integer, i.e. 1 is Monday, 2 is Tuesday etc.

```
`# only select delayed flights`
delayed_flights = df_airports_clean[df_airports_clean['ARR_DELAY_NEW'] >0] 
delayed_flights['DAY_OF_WEEK'].value_counts()

1    44787
7    40678
2    33145
5    29629
4    27991
3    26499
6    24847
Name: DAY_OF_WEEK, dtype: int64
```

How do i convert the above into a time series? Additionally how do i change the integer for the 'day of week' into a string (i.e. 'Monday instead of '1'). i couldn't find the answer to those questions in this forum. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down the problem into two parts.

---

#### Converting the num_delayed columns into a time series

I am not sure what you meant by a `time-series` here. But the below code would work well for your plotting purpose.

```py
delayed_flights = df_airports_clean[df_airports_clean['ARR_DELAY_NEW'] > 0] 
delayed_series = delayed_flights['DAY_OF_WEEK'].value_counts()

delayed_df = pd.DataFrame(delayed_series, columns=['NUM_DELAYS'])
delayed_array = delayed_df['NUM_DELAYS'].values
```

`delayed_array` contains the array of delayed flight counts in order.

---

#### Converting the day in int into a weekday

You can easily do this by using the `calendar` module.

```py
>>> import calendar
>>> calendar.day_name[0]
'Monday'
```

If Monday is not the first day of week, you can use [setfirstweekday](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.setfirstweekday) to change it.

In your case, your day integers are 1-indexed and hence you would need to subtract 1 to make it 0-indexed. Another easy workaround would be to define a dictionary with `keys` as day_int and `values` as weekday.